# L5 custom validation messages not displayed

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm using the following code in my controller action for validation. I'm 100% sure this is the code that's being used for the validation as removing and adding validations is working as expected:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
], [
    'email.required' => 'Vul een e-mailadres in.',
    'email.email' => 'Vul een geldig e-mailadres in.',
    'password.required' => 'Vul een wachtwoord in.'
]);
```

The problem is that it keeps showing the default error messages ("The email field is required.") instead of the messages I'm providing ("Vul een e-mailadres in.").

I'm using the following code to display the errors in the view:

```
{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

I guess this is the right way to do this, because when I choose Go To Declaration of the validate method in PhpStorm I see the following function:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests.php:

public function validate(Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = array())
{
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    }
}
```

Why does it keep displaying the default error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that controller validation uses `ValidatesRequests` and validate method is defined this way:

```
public function validate(Request $request, array $rules)
{
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    }
}
```

You cannot pass here translation. However in your case you should just create `validation.php`  file with your translation in `resources/lang/nl` directory and in your `config/app.php` file set `locale` to `nl`

**EDIT**

I've looked at source and in newer Laravel 5 version, indeed 3rd parameter is used. It seems that new parameter was added and you have old version in compiled file (maybe you have modified `composer.json` or old `composer.json` file).

Whenever you have similiar issues you should run in your console:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

to remove compiled files.

If you don't want to have this file when development, you could remove it from `composer.json` file - you should remove lines with `"php artisan optimize"` however it will affect app performance if you don't restore it and generated new `compiled.php` mfile when running in production.

Comment: This was almost the problem. I updated my question with my version of the method, where the $messages array is accepted (I didn't change the file at all). However, in `storage\framework\compiled.php` your version of the method is being used. After deleting this file it's working. Any idea how this is possible? I'm afraid the problem will come back as it was working this way before too, but suddenly not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Validato::make()` method.

```
$data = Input::all();
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
);
$messages = array(
    'email.required' => 'Vul een e-mailadres in.',
    'email.email' => 'Vul een geldig e-mailadres in.',
    'password.required' => 'Vul een wachtwoord in.'
);
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Response::json(['error' => $validator->errors()->first()]);
}
```